# How can I get my army across the ocean?

Tags: civilization-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get my units on a ship?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7951/how-do-i-get-my-units-on-a-ship)

It's my first game of Civilization V, and I have finished conquering all the cities on my current continent. There are still 2 more civilizations on another continent which I have just discovered using some Caravels.

I have a rather massive army on my main continent, and no apparent way to get any aggressive units onto the other continent. I've spent about 50 turns pumping science and culture because I'm not sure what else to do. How can I move my army, or else get any kind of meaningful ground unit onto the other continent. Even a single settler would do, really.

Comment: @badp These should rather be merged than closed as a duplicate. They are different questions with the same answer.

Comment: Merging implies closing as dupe

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All units that are in your territory after you research **Optics** will receive the Embark upgrade, allowing them to travel across water tiles.  **Astronomy** will turn your littoral navy into a full-fledged blue-water navy, allowing your embarked units (and ships) to cross oceans.